# Sharing the business layer between applications in Scala

Tags: c#, scala, architecture

I have a business logic (domain services/model) which I want to share between two type of projects. One is an mvc web application and another is a terminal/console application.

In .NET world I create a solution with at least three projects (each project will be compiled to a DLL file).

1. Services (library)
2. Web (mvc web application)
3. Console (console application)

Then I would reference to the `Services` from `Web` and `Console` projects. This way `Web` and `Console` applications are using the same `Services` layer and can be run completely separated.

Now I want to do the same work in Scala. I'm looking for the best patterns and practices to do such work.

More over, Is it a good idea to move the **models** from the the `Web` application to the `Services` and use those models in the `Console` app? Actually I'm using the models classes as both domain and mvc models.

NOTE: I don't know if it's important to say, but I use Play as the web application framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create subprojects A, B, C and move all business logic into D.
2. [Make A, B, C depend on jar artifact produced as a result of D](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.3/docs/Getting-Started/Multi-Project.html). (Take a closer look on [**classpath dependencies**](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.3/docs/Getting-Started/Multi-Project.html#classpath-dependencies) section)
3. ????
4. Profit!

Answer (score 0):

You can do exactly the same thing in Scala using any build system, like SBT or Maven. Since you're using Play, the natural choice is SBT. Just make three projects, just as you have described, [using SBT build definitions](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Multi-Project.html).

I don't know about Play specifically, but usually each such project result in JAR (or other *AR) file which can be, for example, run with `java` command or deployed somewhere. So your "Services" and "Console" will presumably be plain JAR files.